# Creating a simple Flv video gallery with (using flex + AIR)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, video, air, gallery

I'm just moving from programming in Flash to Flex.

I want to create a simple gallery which is loaded with locally stored FLV short clips. 
I know how to create a text/image gallery, but I wasn't able to put the VideoDisplay component in the List control.

The final result should be a gallery with videos playing while the cursor is on top of them.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to implement an ItemRenderer which will load the video clip using a Loader, and then put it inside a UIComponent using addChild, and add the UIComponent using addElement for the list.

My problem was that I also wanted full control over the FLV including the option to skip to a specific frame, so I HAD to embed the flv inside a MovieClip, which was only possible in Flash. so I embedded the flvs inside MovieClips in Flash, exported them to a SWC file, and used them in Flex, storing them inside a UIComponent again like the above method.

:)